# How to create toggle navbar in react with redux thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using react with redux thunk. I created one action, two reducers(One parent and one child) And a store. Now i am using reactstrap for navbar and in that, **this.state** method is used for toggling the navbar, But i want to do **toggle** with **dispatching an action** and **setting & getting the state from store**. Below is my code:

/* App.js */

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink } from 'reactstrap';
import { simpleAction } from './actions/simpleAction';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state
})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  simpleAction: () => dispatch(simpleAction())
})

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }
  simpleAction = (event) => {
   this.props.simpleAction();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
          <NavbarBrand href="/">reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/components/">Components</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">GitHub</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

/* simpleAction.js */

```
export const simpleAction = () => dispatch => {
 dispatch({
  type: 'SIMPLE_ACTION',
  payload: 'result_of_simple_action'
 })
}
```

/* simpleReducer.js */

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'SIMPLE_ACTION':
   return {
    result: action.payload
   }
  default:
   return state
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another action in the same file or any file you wanted

```
export const toggleNav = () => dispatch => {
 dispatch({
  type: 'TOGGLE_NAV',
 })
}
```

and a reducer like

```
export default (state = false, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'TOGGLE_NAV':
   return !state;

  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

add it to your combine reducer with key `navStatus` 
and update mapDispatchToProps like following

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  simpleAction: () => dispatch(simpleAction()),
  toggleNav: () => dispatch(toggleNav()),
})
```

add that action on `NavbarToggler` onClick event (`onClick={this.props.toggleNav}`) and set that props to the isOpen prop (`isOpen={this.props.navStatus}`) of `Collapse` component.

### Map Dispatch To Props

mapDispatchToProps is a function, its name can be anything, but for readability, we name it  as `mapDispatchToProps`, it has a parameter `dispatch`, if you want to access an action within a component as props you have to follow this syntax, or you can simply use the following syntax

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { simpleAction, toggleNav })(App);
//or
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { 
  simpleAction: simpleAction,
  toggleNav: toggleNav,
})(App);
```

react-redux will check whether mapDispatchToProps is action or object if the value is object react-redux will do the dispatch operations itslef.

Comment: Upvoted! But answer is not clear because of mapDispatchToProps.

Comment: updated about Map Dispatch To Props, if you want to use a form library try [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/), its react recommended form handling library and redux form is much more expensive than this

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new action for the **toggle** like:

```
export const toggleAction = () => dispatch => {
 dispatch({
  type: 'TOGGLE_ACTION'
 })
}
```

and in reducer:

```
export default (state = { isOpen: false }, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'TOGGLE_ACTION':
   state.isOpen = !state.isOpen;
   return state;

  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

After you can combine the reducers and action onto the connect method of redux.
You can simply use the updated props value onto the `isOpen` attribute.

**EDIT**
the app component will be like:

```
...
import { toggleAction } from './actions/toogleAction';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state
})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  simpleAction: () => dispatch(simpleAction()),
  toggleAction: () => dispatch(toggleAction())
})

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }
  toggle() {
    this.props.toggleAction();
  }
  simpleAction = (event) => {
   this.props.simpleAction();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
          <NavbarBrand href="/">reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
          <Collapse isOpen={this.props.isOpen} navbar>
            ...
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Don't i need to give payload with type 'TOGGLE_ACTION'?

Comment: the payload isn't necessary, the payload type is sufficient as we aren't making any API call so there isn't a response to pass as payload.
We can simply toggle the reducer state as done above.

Comment: Upvoted! But answer is fully understandable as you didn't give example of App component.

Comment: @rajat, I've edited my answer and added app component logic as well.

Comment: can you please tell me, How to manage forms in redux with react?

Comment: I guess you should take a look at https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/gettingstarted.md/... its best coupled with redux app.